# Multiple foreign keys with different types of relationship in the same table (?)

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, entity-relationship

I'm designing a database of different cities in a country that stores information about each of its municipals positions. 
But I am unsure about the relationships between each city and each different type of responsibility.
For example:
Each city may have several political actors (1:N)
Each city has only one president (1:1)
Each city can have many councils and syndics (1:N)

This is my design right now:

[image]

In each of the tables of councils, syndics and president I store two foreign keys.

But the kind of relationship changes for each of the foreign keys.
For example cities to syndics is one to many. But political_actors to syndics is one to one.

Is this statement valid (?)

Comment: It seems to me the president table is redundant.  Couldn't you just have a column in the political_actors table called is_president containing True/False values.  The only drawback is you would lose the constraint that there only be one president for one city.  I don't use mysql, so I'm not sure how hard it would be to add that constraint to the political_actors table.

Comment: Thanks for you answer!!, I redesign the ER database using the suggestion you gave to me, but also add the fields of syndic and council inside the political_actor table becuse a political_actor can only have one public charge at time,  as I am working with rails I will use validations where only one of the three fields is true and the others two must be false, otherwise the application throw an error, this is my desing right now [link]http://i.imgur.com/aMaifPI.png , I'll keep you informed if i succeed